# Google Cloud Genomics Pipeline Zone and Region Specification Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, vcf-variant-call-format

I am new to google cloud and was told to use [Variant Transforms](https://github.com/googlegenomics/gcp-variant-transforms) in order to get .vcf files into Big Query. I did everything specified on the Variant Transforms read me and copy and pasted the first block of code in to a bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Parameters to replace:
GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT
INPUT_PATTERN=gs://BUCKET/*.vcf
OUTPUT_TABLE=GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT:BIGQUERY_DATASET.BIGQUERY_TABLE
TEMP_LOCATION=gs://BUCKET/temp

COMMAND="/opt/gcp_variant_transforms/bin/vcf_to_bq \
  --project ${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT} \
  --input_pattern ${INPUT_PATTERN} \
  --output_table ${OUTPUT_TABLE} \
  --temp_location ${TEMP_LOCATION} \
  --job_name vcf-to-bigquery \
  --runner DataflowRunner"
gcloud alpha genomics pipelines run \
  --project "${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}" \
  --logging "${TEMP_LOCATION}/runner_logs_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).log" \
  --zones us-west1-b \
  --service-account-scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform \
  --docker-image gcr.io/gcp-variant-transforms/gcp-variant-transforms \
  --command-line "${COMMAND}"
```

I tried to run this, while replacing the parameters appropriately and got this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.genomics.pipelines.run) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error: validating pipeline: zones and regions cannot be specified together
```

I since then have tried to specify the region and zone on separate lines and have even changed the default region and zone. I have even tried example pipelines from google themselves and they still result in the same error. Am I doing something wrong or is there just something more I need to install for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the --regions flag first and in the [end](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/genomics/pipelines/run#SYNOPSIS) the --zone flag. As workaround you can set the default [zone and region to your local client](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/#set_default_zone_and_region_in_your_local_client). Also keep in mind that the [region is "us-west1" and the zone is "b"](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/)